# Renaming Admin User on my PC makes my hard disk Full

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I'm having a problem with my hard disk.

I only have 80GB of HD, then I rename my Admin user like (Shaqnet to My PC) then from that time before I rename the administrator I only have 39GB space and a free space of 38GB. After I rename it I notice that I only have 1 GB space. What should I do?

I tried to delete the files, using Control Panel Access but there's only one User account there. When i go to C:\Users I see a folder of the Old user (Shaqnet) and it contains 39GB space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does C:\Users\My PC contain the same data as C:\Users\Shaqnet?

If so, then you're free to delete C:\Users\Shaqnet to restore some free space.

Comment: Yes its the same as C:\Users\My PC

By the way, Thanks for answering. I'll try that later.

Comment: However, when i delete the files on the C:\Users\Shaqnet the folder My Documents has been deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Login with admin account (not standart user)

In explorer menu open: `Tools->Folder Options.`
In the opened window select tab `[View]` and find `[Hidden files and folders]`. Check `Show Hidden files and folders` then apply.

Go to `C:\Users` and if you see hidden (low opacity) folders you can try to delete some data. Be careful.

Comment: Yeah, I did that before. And a folder AppData Appear? It has 39GB file size.